# Perform one function at a time giving priority to one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a code.

```
function myfunc() {
    $("div[id='zeus']")
        .find('a')
        .each(function() {
            if ($(this)
                .text() == "Hey Start") {
                $(this)[0].click();
            }
            else if ($(this)
                .text() == "Refresh") {
                $(this)[0].click();
            }
        });
}
var fill= setInterval(myfunc, 2000)
```

I want the above code to run on a html page where it has 2 links,

1) Hey Start

2) Refresh

I want the code to press the "Refresh" link every 2 seconds(now "Hey Start" link is not present). Due to the clicking of Refresh link the "Hey Start" link appears. Now the problem is the above code is clicking both the links simultaneously from now on. I want to stop the "Refresh" clicking as soon as the "Hey Start" link appears.

Can it be done? Please show it.

Comment: can you create snippet?and post html as well?its hard to understand just by reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple elements to process, but need to execute only one based on option then you can

```js
function myfunc() {
  var array = ['Hey Start', 'Refresh'];
  array.some(function(text) {
    var $el = $("#zeus").find('a:contains("' + text + '")');
    if ($el.length) {
      $('#result').html('clicking on: ' + $el.text())
      $el[0].click();
      return true;
    }
  })
}
var fill = setInterval(myfunc, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zeus">
  <a>Refresh</a>
</div>
<button onclick="$('#zeus').append('<a>Hey Start</a>')">Start</button>
<button onclick="$('#zeus a:contains(\'Hey Start\')').remove()">Remove</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Since you want to process the anchor elements based on priority, you need to define one, since in your case it is based on the text content, here we are using an array which has an ordered list of texts based on its priority. So if there is an anchor with text which is in the array then that anchor will the processed before an anchor whose text comes after that.

The implementation here loops through the array and checks whether there is an anchor with the given text, if so then it triggers the click event of that element, and it returns `true`, so that none of the elements after the current item is processed([See Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

Comment: I don't know how but it worked for me. thank you very much. But I have 1 request. I am novice at all these so can you please explain the code to me. How it works? If you want to. @arun-p-johny

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're iterating about every `a` found in the `#zeus`...

So, if you clicked one link and you don't want to click another link you must jump outside the `each`-loop somehow.

Break it by returning `false`, like on the documentation page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ when some conditions are met. E.g. add [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to one link or add a [class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Simple solution:

```
function myfunc() {
    $("div[id='zeus']")
        .find('a')
        .each(function() {
            if ($(this)
                .text() == "Hey Start") {
                $(this)[0].click();
                return false;
            }
            else if ($(this)
                .text() == "Refresh") {
                $(this)[0].click();
                return false;
            }
        });
}
var fill= setInterval(myfunc, 2000)
```